# Запятая перед сравнительным оборотом не стоит, поясните!

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот, правила

> 3. Обороты с "как" не выделяются запятыми:
>
> 2) если основное значение оборота - приравнивание или отождествление (но не уподобление): Старайтесь смотреть на меня как на пациента, одержимого болезнью, вам еще неизвестной.

P.S: что значит "не уподобление"? не пойму.

Пример с уподоблением (в чем разница?): Она то ластится, как змей, то жжёт и плещет, будто пламень, то давит мысль мою, как камень.

PP.S: Благодарность Sharon'у.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) В этой теме нужно разбираться в **терминологических особенностях.**

**В художественных произведениях** используется такое средство выразительности, как **сравнение,** при этом автор обнаруживает сходство в разных предметах по какому-либо признаку.

Например: *Она то ластится, как (ластится) змей,  то давит мысль мою, как (давит) камень.* Два предмета сравниваются (уподобляются) между собой **по их действию.**

В правилах Розенталь  всю тему называет "Сравнительный оборот", но при этом **художественное сравнение считает уподоблением**, а оборот со значением "в качестве, рассматривая" —  **приравниванием или отождествлением**.

2) *Она то ластится, **как змей**, то жжёт и плещет, будто **пламень**, то давит мысль мою, как **камень**.*

Сравнительный оборот здесь имеет значение уподобления  (она похожа на камень), но это **не отождествление и не приравнивание** (она не является камнем). **Оборот со значением уподобления обособляется.**

*Старайтесь смотреть на меня **как на пациента,** одержимого болезнью, вам еще неизвестной.*

Здесь   значение **отождествления или уподобления** (считайте меня пациентом),   поэтому **оборот не обособляется.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Чтобы не путаться в этой теме, лучше рассматривать два варианта: уподобление/сравнение и тождество.

Это **принципиальное деление**, дальше орфограмма для каждой темы будет иметь свое решение.

**1) Уподобление/сравнение:** один предмет похож на другой (по какому-то признаку или действию):

Пример:

*И всё-таки я, **как (будто) отчаявшийся пациент**, старался найти хотя бы какое-то лекарство для своей души.*

**2) Тождество:** один предмет приравнивается к другому, хотя и не равен ему.

**Значения разные**: считая, рассматривая, воспринимая, отождествляя (кстати, значение "в качестве" относится тоже к тождеству).

**Не стоит их рассматривать отдельно**, всё это одна и та же тема, с одним решением.

Примеры:

*Старайтесь смотреть на меня **как на пациента**, одержимого болезнью, вам еще неизвестной.*

*Он относился ко мне **как к своему пациенту***.

*Я к вам пришел **как пациент*** (в качестве пациента).

Comment: Еще раз Вас благодарю! Я вчера долго не ждал ответов - не видел ничего. Сегодня в обед только прочел. 

К stackexchange.com я еще не привык, хотя вопросов задавать умею плохо (честно говоря). Пытаюсь их решать самостоятельно, гуглом (так быстрее, иначе есть вероятность почувствовать себя глупо, если до меня "дойдет"). Признаю, что с форумом решать веселее, так как появляется обязательство (вроде, "то что написано пером - не вырубишь топором"); и не будет нерешенных, отложенных вопросов. Попробую научиться их задавать!

Comment: Учебник Розенталя интересный! Однако, в нем нет ответов =( Спасает то, что предложения хорошо находятся в сети: получается понять логику учебных примеров и правил, которые не всегда ясно понимаемы. Мне так кажется.

Comment: Ваше дополнение прочитал. Постараюсь не путаться, хоть зачастую делаю это.

Comment: (1 ) Рустам, заходите на форум и задавайте ваши вопросы, вам обязательно ответят. (2) Розенталь - это лучший и официальный источник, с ним лучше подружиться. Практически там есть ответы на все вопросы (я так считаю). все остальные учебные сайты его просто цитируют, слегка переделав.  Но сам текст правил читается не всегда понятно, я бы порекомендовала вам не спеша и вдумчиво законспектировать его, взяв за основу, а потом добавлять туда текущие материалы. (3) Обороты с союзом КАК - сложная тема, ей нужно уделить особое внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Sharon, большое Вам спасибо, что ответили!! Вроде понял. Привожу свой анализ, как понял. Если что не так, комментируйте (я, возможно, ошибаюсь)! Я иду по пособию Д.Э.Розенталь.

**Приравнение** - это, когда кто-то приравнивает кого-то к кому-то. *Анализ пр-ра с пациентом*: Я являюсь вашим пациентом, возможно, Вы еще не знаете этого.

**Отождествление** - это, когда кто-то отождествляет кого-то к кому-то. *Анализ пр-ра с пациентом*: Я не являюсь вашим пациентом, Вы это знаете, но это неважно, поэтому, считайте меня своим пациентом (представьте, что я Ваш пациент).

**Уподобление** - это, когда кто-то подобен кому-то. *Анализ пр-ра со змеей*: Она не является змеей, глупо было бы так считать, но похожа на змею ...

Comment: Рустам, я  на Ваши вопросы ответила в дополнении, посмотрите, пожалуйста.